# How to catch BeanCreationException error?

Tags: java, spring

We have a Spring based application, with several `@Services`.

When a `@Service` fails to start (i.e: db down, wrong credentials, and so forth), the application still runs - but in a Zombie state: It's up, but nothing works.

How can I tell Spring to exit on `BeanCreationException`? Or, if not possible, how do I catch it?

Comment: is it a web a application?

Comment: @zakariaamine Yep

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. Based on what you provided I would do it this way:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalExceptionHandler {

     @Autowired
     ApplicationContext context;

    @ExceptionHandler(BeanCreationException.class)
    public void handleConflict() {
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();
    }
}
```

or add life cycle events handling on the services that fail:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

        @Autowired
         ApplicationContext context;

// you code

   @PreDestroy
    public void cleanUp() throws Exception {
       ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();

    }
}
```

I hope that helps.